# How do I use importlib.resources with pickle files?

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, python-importlib

I'm trying to load a pickle file with `importlib.resources`, but I'm getting the following error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte`

The bit that is raising the error is:

```py
with importlib.resources.open_text("directory_with_pickle_file", "pickle_file.pkl") as f:
   data = pickle.load(f)
```

I'm certain that the file (`pickle_file.pkl`) was created with `pickle.dump`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through lots of trial and error I figured out that `importlib.resources` has a `read_binary` function which can be used to read pickled files like so:

```py
text = importlib.resources.read_binary("directory_with_pickle_file", "pickle_file.pkl")
data = pickle.loads(text)
```

Here, `data` is the pickled object.